# Error in running java code in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I recently installed the open-jdk 7 in my ubuntu server.
But the version is still displayed as :

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

And if i try to run a java program i get the foll exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hello : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Which is the consequence of compiling the program with a higher jdk and trying to run in a lower one.
How can i correct this.

**Edit**:But when i do javac -version I get javac 1.7.0_09 as the response.

Comment: There's a javac flag that tells it to compile so it is compatible with lower version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like:

1) You have multiple versions of Java installed (which is perfectly OK to do!) ... and ...

2) "javac" is picking up the correct version ... but "java" is picking up a different version.

SOLUTION:

[update-java-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-java-alternatives.8.html)

For example, look at this link:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/64329/how-to-replace-openjdk-6-with-openjdk-7
>
> ```
> # EXAMPLE:
> $ update-java-alternatives -l
> java-1.6.0-openjdk 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
> java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1051 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
> $ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Move the source over and recompile on the ubuntu box?

Comment: I did recompile it again but its not working.And how come my jdk version did not change when I installed open-jdk 7. Dosen't version 51.0 indicate that its complied with jdk 7. But when i do javac -version I get javac 1.7.0_09

Answer (score 0):

Probably the newly installed JDK is in another directory that's not part of your $PATH(very common). I would do a find / -name "javac" and see how many entries are found.

You'll probably find more than one.